# App fails to connect to Google Play licensing service?

Tags: android, google-play

I have incorporated the Google Play licensing library into my app and tests are running fine on two of my devices (Samsung Galaxy S2 and HTC Desire HD). However, when trying to do the licensing check on a third device - HTC Wildfire S - it fails to connect to the service, returning with a "don't allow / retry" response every time. Really confused by this behaviour. Anyone have any ideas at all what might be up? The phone is running Android version 2.3.5, has the latest version of Google Play (3.9.16), I am logged into my Google Play account and I have an active internet connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two weeks on and without making any changes to my licensing code, I went back and tried this on my HTC Wildfire S and strangely (but delightfully!) it's working now. Must have been a temporary problem with the Google Play licensing service rather than my code...